# Is @ useful in comment?

Tags: discussion, comment-replies

When I ask some questions, someone would like to reply in comment. So I communicate with them in comment. To tell them I have replied to them, I @mention their ID at comment beginning. But it doesn't become a link. So I don't know if it is useful. If it doesn't work, how should I reply to them in comment?

Comment: _“it doesn't become blue”_ — you mean it doesn’t become a link?

Comment: If you mean a link: cross-site post on Meta.SE: [@<name> comments should link to the named person's profile (like twitter)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9652/289905). It’s [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: Maybe the FAQ from the uber-meta is helpful: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)?

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Yes, I think it should give a feedback to users. Just like other websites. And add a convenient key to use it. If I want to @ you, I should copy your ID at first, then paste in my comment. It's very easy to click in your homepage.  And I don't know how it process space in ID. Such as somebody's ID is `Sebastian Simon Yes`, who I have @ in this comment? You or `Sebastian Simon Yes`?

Comment: @张庆昊 you can press tab to select the username, and it will remove spaces etc. automatically. e.g. `@SebastianSimon` See the link from rene to see how exactly it works.

Comment: @mu in addition, you don't even have to type the complete name.

Comment: Why do you expect the name to become a link?

Comment: @deceze probably from other forums/boards/messengers on the internet. Some do automatically format `@someuser` to become a link to `someuser`'s profile. Quite common, really. If I recall correctly, most IRC clients did that back in the day, too. The tradition remains in modern IMs like Slack or Discord.

Comment: @deceze♦  If the name to become a link, it give me a feedback that I succeeded in @, so that I wouldn't post this question(this question have received ten negative votes... I don't know why...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is useful, because, although it doesn't become a link, the mentioned user will get a notification in their inbox.

Users get notified about a comment, if...

- the user owns the post, or
- the user was mentioned and was previously active on the post

Comment: RE: "the user was mentioned", only if they've been active on the post. Like commenting or editing or something. Sometimes they will not show up as autocomplete suggestion (e.g., somebody who closes a question) but they will be notified. You cannot mention a random unrelated user and expect them to be notified. At the very least, there is a potential problem with duplicate names - usernames are not unique on SO, so there *are* users with duplicate names.

Comment: @VLAZ I've edited my answer. Is it OK now?